# Next JS : Make a Post Request to Stripe in Order to Add Multiple Items to Cart

Tags: javascript, post, next.js, stripe-payments

NEXT JS: I am trying to put the content of a state variable "cart" into the body of the POST request to the STRIPE API.
Cart has the format `[{id: 1, amount: 1}, {id: , amount: }.......]`

I tried putting items directly into the API handler (`list_items`) and that works. But I cannot get my "cart" variable to show up there, so I guess I have to include the items in the POST request itself. Have tried getting that to run (including an object there and `JSON.stringify` as property to a `line_items` - variable, but to no avail.
Maybe somebody could help me out?

API handler:

```js
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {

  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.send({
      error: 'Method need to be POST',
    });
  }
  const domainURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

  // const { quantity, mode, productKey } = req.body;

  const pmTypes = ['card'];
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: pmTypes,
    mode: 'payment',
    locale: 'en',
    line_items: the_variable????,

    success_url: `${domainURL}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domainURL}/cart`,
  });

  res.send({
    sessionId: session.id,
  });
}
```

POST request :

```js
 const stripeLoader = loadStripe(props.pk);
  const redirectToCheckout = async () => {
    const stripeClient = await stripeLoader;

    const { sessionId } = await fetch('api/checkout_sessions', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body : {????}
    }).then((res) => res.json());

    stripeClient.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any structure you like to communicate between your client and backend, but your API request to Stripe to create the session must conform to the `line_items` API parameter expected shape ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items)).

You can either define pricing [on the fly](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers) with `price_data` on each item:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'T-shirt',
          },
          unit_amount: 2000,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
    cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  });
```

Or you can use [predefined prices](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#create-product-prices-upfront):

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [{
    price: 'price_123',
    quantity: 1,
  },{
    price: 'price_456',
    quantity: 3,
  }],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nolan! Didn't know about pricing on the fly, will certainly come in handy in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make the POST request. The body has to look like this:

```js
body: JSON.stringify({
        lineItems: props.cart.map((singleItem) => {
          return {
            price: <the_stripe_price_key_for_the_given_product>,
            quantity: <the_amount>,
          };
        }),
      })
```

included the following line in the API handler: `const { lineItems } = req.body;`
and set `line_items: lineItems`

So, just as Nolan pointed out, line_items will accept an array of objects (in my case generated through mapping of my 'cart' state variable).

Answer (score 0):

I did something a little different to get multiple cart items dynamically into my API.
Here is my front end.

```js
export default function PreviewPage() {
// this is just example data you can add to this list 
//how you would like to.
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    codesToSend:[
      { price: 'price_1iasdhfwie8', quantity: 1 },
      { price: 'price_i383829wdff', quantity: 1 },
    ]
  });
```

```js
const submitHandler = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();


  const response = await fetch('/api/checkout_sessions', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({

      formData

    }),
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
  }


  const result = await response.json();
  console.log(result)

  // Redirect the user to the Stripe checkout session URL
  window.location.href = result.url;
};
```

And in my backend I'm sending the url for redirect as a 200 response and sending the url as json back to my front end.

```js
if (req.method === 'POST') {
  const { formData } = await req.body;
  console.log(formData)

  const codesToSend= formData.codesToSend
  
  try {

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      line_items:
      codesToSend,
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
      cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      automatic_tax: { enabled: true },
    });
    // console.log(session.url)
    res.status(200).json({ url: session.url });
    } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
  }
} 
else {
  res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
  res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
}
```